# Tmux Colors Not Working

Tags: 16.04, tmux

I have a bit of an odd issue as far as I can tell. When I use `tmux` I don't get color within the terminal (all text is white, even for things like `ls`), but my colors work perfectly for vim and other things like that.

In my .tmux.conf file I have the line `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"`, which is what most people say solved their problems. I also tried starting tmux by typing `tmux -2`, but that doesn't change anything.

I'm kind of at a loss at this point, so thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Tmux Version: 2.1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I can help you solve the symptom, but not the root of the problem.
The design of the prompt is configured in the variable PS1.

Outside tmux, this is the value:

```
$ echo ${PS1} # outside tmux
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$
```

This is the value inside tmux:

```
$ echo ${PS1} # outside tmux
${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
```

to fix the problem, you can run this command inside tmux, and the prompt will immediately look normal for the current window:

```
PS1='\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

edit:
I solved it by adding the following line to ~/.tmux.conf

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

Comment: The last line saved my time! happy bashing :)

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit of an old one. I resolved this issue by creating a `.bash_profile` file and sourcing my `.bashrc` file.

To do this, add `source ~/.bashrc` to your .bash_profile file.

The problem in my case was due to my bashrc settings not being sourced via tmux. Tmux runs as a login shell so it looks for a `.bash_profile` file or a `.bash_login` file.
My colours were being set in my `.bashrc` file.

Comment: this is the only answer that worked for me. Thx. Do you know you to use a theme in tmux? For exmaple this: https://github.com/seebi/tmux-colors-solarized

Comment: @wwwwwwwwwwww sorry I've only just seen this. Have you figured it out?

Comment: Great point, this is the answer if you use a `.bash_profile`

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to solve this:
open .bash_profile

```
vi .bash_profile
```

Save the following config's

```
export PS1="\[$(tput bold)$(tput setb 2)$(tput setaf 2)\]\u@\h:\w $ \[$(tput sgr0)\]"
  alias ls='ls --color'
  alias dir='dir --color'
  alias vdir='vdir --color'
  alias grep='grep --color'
  alias fgrep='fgrep --color'
  alias egrep='egrep --color'
```

Source the bash profile

```
source .bash_profile
```

There will be colours on tmux